# Disabling the scroll on a combobox dropdown

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Right now I am adding search box within the dropdown of a combobox in WPF. Only items that match the search will be displayed in the dropdown.

The search box works correctly but I have noticed that if there are many items in the dropdown, scrolling down will scroll the search box offscreen. Is there a way to partition off the search box into its own section of the dropdown that does not scroll (like frozen rows in a spreadsheet)?

The other items of the dropdown are inserted into the combobox.items collection to be displayed in the itempanel. I have tried disabling the scroll behavior and inserting the items into a subcontrol but that leads to wonky behavior in the search.

Comment: have you considered altering the combo box control template?

Comment: @bleepzter I have tried that approach but the problem is that I wish to only alter the contents of the dropdown, part of which is dynamically generated.